Reusing the invoked Function's type for Hook types
If I don't use a separate function, TypeScript can easily infer the function parameters and can effectively use the result of processFn to declare the Result type.
I want to achieve the same thing, but not with a function embedded in the options, rather with a separately declared function.

TypeScript Playground

// Playground Content

export const useModel = <Source, Result>(
  sources: Source[],
  _options: {
    processFn: (data: Source) => Result,
  },
): {
  value: Result[]
} => {
  return {
    value: sources.map((source) => _options.processFn(source))
  }
}

const exampleSources = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Test#1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Test#2' },
]
const myModel = useModel(exampleSources, {
  // TypeScript can clearly infer the type of source
  processFn: (source) => {
    return {
      resultName: 'ResultTest#' + source.id 
    }
  },
})

/*
myModel.value will: [
  { resultName: 'ResultTest#1' },
  { resultName: 'ResultTest#2' },
]
*/

If I want to pass a separate function as processFn, I would expect that the const process = () => {...} immediately inherits the processFn type; but it doesn't. How can I tell process that it should actually have the type of useModel's _options.processFn?

TypeScript Playground

// Playground Content

export const useModel = <Source, Result>(
  sources: Source[],
  _options: {
    processFn: (data: Source) => Result,
  },
): {
  value: Result[]
} => {
  return {
    value: sources.map((source) => _options.processFn(source))
  }
}

// How do I specify that it is the processFn function of useModel?
// I would expect that since I'm using process as processFn, the type of source would be Source instead of any.
const process = (source) => {
  return {
    resultName: 'ResultTest#' + source.id 
  }
}

const exampleSources = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Test#1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Test#2' },
]
const myModel = useModel(exampleSources, {
  processFn: process, // Here: I would expect that process automatically takes the processFn type because of this, but that's not what happens
})

/*
myModel.value will: [
  { resultName: 'ResultTest#1' },
  { resultName: 'ResultTest#2' },
]
*/

I would like to avoid declaring the types multiple times, as I believe everything can be inferred from the useModel function's type. However, if I enforce the useModel type on process, I get an error stating that it cannot reference itself. The error message makes some sense, and I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something.
I know this looks silly, I just shared my idea. Since each useModel declaration can have a unique source-result pair, I wanted to tie the process specifically to a given myModel that is meant for it.

TypeScript Playground


'process' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation. (2502)


Trying to read through and understand the code • conventionally K is not "the next type parameter to use after T", it's supposed to represent a key type. If you introduce K that isn't K extends keyof something, it's potentially confusing and adds cognitive load to readers. Please [edit] to change that... maybe to U (which is often "the next type parameter to use after T)? • Also, generally speaking, a [mre] should fit on a single screen of code so nobody has to scroll up and down to understand it. That means you should conserve vertical space where possible.

(see prev comments) typeof Function? That's the type of the Function constructor. Are you using new Function() anywhere? If not, what's typeof Function doing? Do you just mean Function? Or... what is that? • I must admit I'm having trouble understanding what's going on; is this really a minimal example? If so, could you show the manual specification of T, U that you don't want to do, just so that I can see what type it's supposed to be when you don't have a circularity error?

wait, oof, (data: UseModelOptions<T, U>['hooks'] extends { beforeAllProcess: Function } ? U : T) => U inside the definition of UseModelOptions is almost certainly not what you want to do. That's always going to be just T. It's a very longwinded way of writing T, because UseModelOptions<T, U>['hooks'] is always just {beforeAllProcess?: (data: T) => U}, which is optional, so it doesn't extend the required beforeAllProcess. You don't get dynamic types just by referencing the type name again. Before we can even get to the circularity, you need to resolve this.

I think this just plain isn't a [mre] of anything I can handle, sorry for all the comments. My suggestion is to rework this example to be simpler, and one where, if you do specify T and U, it works how you want, and then we can work on having things get inferred for you. I'll disengage now, good luck!

First of all, thank you so much for taking the time to review it and share your opinion! It helps a lot. Soon, I'll try to extract the essence from it; I had a feeling even from the start that it might still be too much. Really, thank you for your time.

I tried to simplify the example. The main question is how I can declare a separate function (second code snippet) in a similar way to the function declared within the options (first code snippet).

I think I see what's happening now. Type inference fundamentally does not work this way. If you define the function inline then there is context for its parameter type. Context is necessarily local; if you are defining the function ahead of time then it cannot have its parameter type inferred by how it's used in an arbitrary place later in the code. That would be an unbounded amount of work for the compiler, PLUS spooky action-at-a-distance (what if it is used 0 times or in 2 diff ways?)

(see prev comment) Maybe there's some way to use a builder or something to get this to work, or some more complicated thing, but it's all just more difficult and convoluted than merely annotating your callback parameters. I'll think about it more, but I really doubt there's anything better than just doing the thing you don't want to do. The cure is likely to be worse than the disease.

Yes, you're absolutely right. I also see only one way, which is that I have to pass the types everywhere. Ultimately, that's not a problem; I just thought there might be some simpler solution I wasn't aware of. Thanks again for the overview, I think I have to agree with your statement that the expected result would cost too much, and anyway, it doesn't take long to pass two types.
